# GridLayoutManager set column and row count

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I used `GridLayoutManager` for `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL` orientation. SpanCount is not work correctly for me, because it depend from layout orientation, but i know how much columns and rows i need. How i can do it?

From documentation to `setSpanCount(int spanCount)`:

```
/**
 * Sets the number of spans to be laid out.
 * <p>
 * If {@link #getOrientation()} is {@link #VERTICAL}, this is the number of columns.
 * If {@link #getOrientation()} is {@link #HORIZONTAL}, this is the number of rows.
 *
 * @param spanCount The total number of spans in the grid
 * @see #getSpanCount()
 */
```

Example: My `RecyclerView` size is `match_parent`, if i have 9 items, i have grid 3x3, if i have 5 items, i have grid 3x2, but i want 2x3.

P.S. I dont want set `GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL` layout orientation.

In screenshot is not correctly, i want grid 2x3.

[image: it is not correct for me]

Answer (score 1):

Created a custom GridlayoutManager while solving a similar problem using the following feature.

> Create a default LayoutParams object for a child of the RecyclerView.

It consists of `generateDefaultLayoutParams` and 3 more functions to set a specific(fixed) layout params to the layoutmanager. This allows to set specific count for both rows and columns.

Link for the same:- https://gist.github.com/KaveriKR/04bfef5ffc9c00a8b6fca503da497322

Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should set span count dynamically, based on your data size.

```
gridLayoutManager.setSpanCount( (int) Math.ceil( data.size() / 3f ) );
```

So for 7, 8 and 9 items, you have 3 rows. For 4, 5 and 6, 2 rows, and so on.
It is important to use float (3f) so your division don't get truncated.

Comment: it leaves space between the rows when its say 4-6 items

Comment: i want to do the same, but `3f` has to be dynamic, how can i get this? I am clueless.